# Using a WPF Polygon in another thread

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm having an issue when passing an object of type Dictionary(Of Int16, Polygon) as an argument to a backgroundworker so the background worker is able to access the Polygons in the Dictionary. I'm getting the typical "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" message. Heres what i have:

```
                Dim worker As New BackgroundWorker
                AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf MeasurePolygons
                AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted

                worker.RunWorkerAsync(PolygonCollection)
```

PolygonCollection is a private variable declared at the top of the class and it is of type Dictionary(Of Int16, Polygon). It will contain 1-10 polygons in it and i want to pass this collection to the backgroundworker because i do calculations on each polygon in the dictionary.

```
    Dim TempPolygonCollection As Dictionary(Of Int16, Polygon)
    TempPolygonCollection = CType(e.Argument, Dictionary(Of Int16, Polygon))
    For i = 0 To TempPolygonCollection.Count - 1
            If TempPolygonCollection.ContainsKey(CShort(i)) Then
                Dim rtb As New RenderTargetBitmap(CInt(800), CInt(600), 96D, 96D, PixelFormats.Default)
                rtb.Render(TempPolygonCollection.Item(CShort(i)))
                Dim encoder As New BmpBitmapEncoder
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb))
            End If
    Next i
```

the error occurs on the rtb.Render(TempPolygonCollection.Item(CShort(i))). Any help would be really appreciated. thanks.

EDIT:
So the 2 friendly posters helped me narrow down my issue but I'm still stuck on how to figure it out.

The Current Problem: I have an object of type Dictionary(Of Int16, Polygon). I need to be able to access each individual Polygon,which are created on the UI thread, inside this Dictionary with the BackgroundWorker. Then on the backgroundworker i will be creating a bitmap file based on the Polygon in the Dictionary. So how can I get access to the Polygons on the backgroundworker? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying your question title. Maybe this will attract someone who knows about these things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `Dictionary`, the problem is the `Polygon` stored in the Dictionary. These are WPF UI elements created in the UI thread, so only the UI thread can use them.

You could execute the `Render` operation into the UI thread (using `Dispatcher.Invoke`). This would mean that the rendering blocks your UI thread, but at least *in between* the render operations, the UI thread would be able to handle other things, i.e., the UI should stay responsive if the time required for a single render operation is not too long.

Comment: Interesting.. So what would I need to do to get them or a copy of them to be accessible to the backgroundworker?

Comment: well I'm taking these polygons and creating bitmap files out of them.. so i was intentionally trying to create the bitmaps on the background thread because creating 10 bitmaps out of 10 different polygons can take 10-15 seconds or so. So i was using the UI thread to display a loading animation to give feedback to the user that it isn't frozen.

Comment: @bflosabre: Is it possible for you to create the Polygons in the background thread as well?

Comment: The polygons are created based on user input on an InkCanvas. So the user basically draws a shape, clicks a button and the Polygon gets created based on the strokes in the InkCanvas. So I'm not sure how i would go about creating the polygons in the backgroundthread..

Comment: @bflosabre91: I see. Yes, that sounds difficult. The only thing I could think of is to take all relevant information out of the Polygon, pass it to your Background thread and recreate a Polygon there. The Polygon's point collection, for example (`Polygon.Point`), is Freezable, which means that you can pass it across thread boundaries after `.Freeze`ing it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx). Sorry, cannot think of a better solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in WPF, the `Polygon` objects can't be used on a thread other than the one that created them.  This means that you can't access any of their properties, or attempt to render them into a `RenderTargetBitmap`.

If you are trying to not block the UI while rendering all these images, I would suggest using the `Dispatcher` to break up the work (schedule them at the `Background` priority).  That way, while an individual save is happening on the UI thread, the `Dispatcher` can interleave mouse input, rendering, etc. so the UI won't get blocked.